# Error accents rest django framework

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I have the problem that it is not recognizing the accents in the rest Json returned with django restframework

```
{"areas": [{"nombre": "Energ\u00eda", "latitude": "-4.0319980", "longitude": "-79.1996880", "marcador": "imagenes/areas/energia_2.png", "bloques":
```

and use renderer_classes = (UnicodeJSONRenderer,) but I still have the problem

please help

Comment: Did you ever solved this? I'm having the same error but when receiving the json data in the requests.

Comment: the error was only in the browser, in my case the answer from android worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this at the beginning of your script:

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

See this:
[Django: Non-ASCII character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635188/django-non-ascii-character)