# python syntax error : non-ascii character

Tags: python, syntax-error, non-ascii-characters

Hi I'm trying understand why I'm getting this error.

when I deploy my project on google appengine, getting error like below

SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xea' in file /base/data/home/apps/s~frikijihyo/1.377756632466273994/app/controllers.py on line 32, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

my code: python

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    flash(u'Korean 게시글을 작성했습니다.', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('article_list'))
```

i wrote `coding: utf-8`.

what is 'character \xea'?
how can i solve this problem?

Comment: please have a look here hope it will solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635188/django-non-ascii-character

Comment: Is your `coding` declaration at the top of your file?

Comment: Can you provide a hex dump of (pertinent parts of) line 32?  `sed -n 32p app/controllers.py | xxd` and edit your question to include this information.

Comment: Also maybe the first line just to see that there's nothing funny in the `coding:` declaration.  Are you on Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Use Python 3 and you have implicit UTF-8 coding for all source files, among all the other goodies.

Comment: Though then ofc GAE does not support 3 directly.

Answer (score 2):

> > what is 'character \xea'?

`\xea` is the first byte of the utf-8 encoding of `'게'`. It is the first non-ASCII byte in your source-code file.

> > how can i solve this problem?

Ensure that the "coding" comment is on one of the first two lines of the file. If the comment appears anywhere else, it has no effect.